# Scrolling to change size of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that for design purposes features a large image and a small div for text.  On the mobile (small screen) I want that text div to enlarge from lower right corner to fill the screen.  Is there a way to have the element go from 25% to a max of 90% on scroll?  Can it be done smoothly as the scroll occurs say within 100 pixel scroll?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a JavaScript solution would be much simpler. Also, I'm not even sure it is possible with CSS alone.

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS alone

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that specific div has id "div", then here is a simple solution that should work

```
$.ready(function()
{
    var init_x = $('#div').offset().left;
    var init_y = $('#div').offset().top;
    var init_fs = $('#div').css('font-size');
    $('#div').scroll(function()
    {
        var ma = 90;
        var mi = 25;
        var threshold = 100;
        var distance = $('#div').top - $(window).top;
        if(distance <= threshold && distance >= 0)
        {
            var new_size = (distance/threshold % (ma-mi+1)) + mi;
            var new_left = init_x*(1 - ((distance/threshold % (ma-mi+1)) + mi); 
            var new_top = init_y*(1 - ((distance/threshold % (ma-mi+1)) + mi); 
            $('#div').offset(new_left, new_top)
            $('#div').css({'font-size': new_size.toString() + "%" });
        } else {
            $('#div').css({'font-size': init_fs });
            $('#div').offset(init_x, init_y);
        }
    });
});
```

This would also make it so that once you scroll more than `threshold` pixels passed the div, its settings would go back to its initial settings, but you could remove that behaviour.

Also, in order for this to work, make sure that the specific div with id "div" has `position: absolute;` in its css;

Comment: I tried this but could not get it to work.  Could you write it up in a codepen?  There must be something I'm missing.  Thanks in Advance!